# How to fix broken Visual Studio project dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, projects-and-solutions

I'm working in a project for a customer where one solutions has 3 projects.
Project A is the base, then project B depends on A, and project C depends on B. By the way, project C is the application, A and B are class libraries.

Usually, I can make a change in project A without the need of manually recompile B and C because Visual Studio does it automatically for me.

However, in this environment (after downloading the solution via Ankh SVN), the dependencies are somewhat not recognized when executing. I'm forced to manually recompile the dominant projects of the dependency hierarchy.

Why is this happening? and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the Solution + Project files are not complete, if a previous programmer had certain settings in his/her global development environment (such as paths).  Have you confirmed that the project dependencies are still in place?  Also, have you confirmed that the paths to the output files of A and B are not explicitly listed in A, B, or C (as opposed to using the defaults, and allowing VS to manage it due to A and B being set as dependencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added the references of project B and project C as a *project* and you didn't add the project output as an *assembly* reference.